# When do abilities and gear give bonus dice?

Tags: skills, equipment, danger-patrol

I am currently looking into [Danger Patrol](http://www.dangerpatrol.com) and I don’t really understand when abilities and gear apply (those that give bonus dice). Is there a description of them somewhere, is this planned for a future supplement/edition, or is it meant to be just made up by the players and GM following the name, which would surely fit the character of the game well and be a lot of fun?

Examples for abilities:

- Atomic Speed
- Psychic Aura
- Precision Sensors

Examples for gear:

- Electro-Shield Gauntlet
- Omni-Scanner
- Frag-Grenades

This question is about the Beta Playtest, but if there are any differences to the Pocket Edition it would be great to know them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They apply whenever you can justify them. Danger Patrol is played like a 50's style tv show, think Flash Gordon on the A Team. Accept technobabble, flimsy logic and the Rule of Cool. if you Scientist wants to use Experimental Device 1 to slow down time to get a better shot, let him! if he uses Experimental Device 1 later it doesn't even have to do the same thing! Frag Grenades can be used to attack, rocket jump, intimidate, propel something in the void of space or whatever your players can justify to themselves and/or you!

Have fun with it and only say no if they cannot make up a fun way to say *how* they use it!

Comment: Thats actually as cool as I hoped it would be. Sounds like a lot of fun, I definitely will have to try this game! Thanks for the answer!